# inner join issue mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My following query is shoqing a very weird error:

statement is right

```
SELECT
users.age,
users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.`gender`,
users.username,
users.`password`,
users.id_user_type,
gender.id
FROM 
user_types
INNER JOIN users ON `gender`.id = users.gender
```

Gender is also another table having ID,gender as two columns

Error i am getting

```
[SQL]SELECT
users.age,
users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.`gender`,
users.username,
users.`password`,
users.id_user_type, 
gender.id
FROM 
user_types
INNER JOIN users ON `gender`.id = users.gender

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'gender.id' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `gender` table in your query but `users` and `user_types`. Either change table user_types to gender or use the correct table alias

```
SELECT
  users.age,
  users.firstname,
  users.lastname,
  users.gender,
  users.username,
  users.password,
  users.id_user_type,
  gender.id
FROM gender --use gender here
INNER JOIN users 
ON gender.id = users.gender
```

As side note `gender` and `password` are not reserved keywords so they don't need to be escaped with backticks. I would suggest to avoid use of backticks where they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't selecting from the table gender or joining it? You need the table general as a join before this one or in the from tables. Else how does it know where to get the data from gender?

Liam